# Generator furnace feed

Tags: electrical

I have added a covered male plug (for a 30 amp  ONAN RV generator feed) above the HVAC cut-off switch in the circuit to the furnace .I have left the neutral and ground coming from that circuit connected to the main panel and only the hot line, which is switched, will be interrupted by the switch to prevent back feeding the panel.The neutral and ground will thus be connected to both the generator and the panel when the switch isolates the hot from the panel.
Will this avoid the neutral/ground bonding issue and allow the furnace to work?/

Comment: Is it a portable generator or an RV generator?  Did you do this in an RV or in a home?  What is the generator model?  Does it have bonded or floating neutral?   Is the generator ONLY feeding the furnace, and nothing else?   Are you saying the generator won't backfeed the panel because you will throw the switch before using it, or the generator can't backfeed the panel because it's a lockout switch that, when "on" to the breaker, disconnects the inlet?  It's subtle, but it has to be the latter.  Is the "covered male plug" an actual inlet, or something home-made?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a premade single-circuit transfer switch/inlet combination (Reliance Controls makes 'em, but I can't recall what they're called offhand) for this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your generator. Onans are a bit obsolete so I assume there will be other generators in your future.

If the generator has its own neutral-ground bond, as *portable* generators generally do, then you need to switch neutral together with hot, meaning you need a DPDT switch. Ones approved for household wiring are expensive.

If the generator isolates neutral from ground, as is common for stationary generators, then you do not need to switch neutral and an SPDT (common 3-way if it is rated for the service) switch is perfectly fine.

Really, the right way to solve this is a generator subpanel.  Just a basic Siemens 12-space panel, two 2-pole breakers for the ECSBPK01 or '02 interlock.  If you need to switch neutral, then use the 2 phases on the panel as hot and neutral. (yeah, you can do that).
Then put as many circuits in that panel as you please.

Comment: The gen is ONAN 4KYFA26100K  meant to be stationary.I have adapted it to be sort-of portable.I have just used the SPST switch for the furnace circuit cut off as the means to isolate the hot (line L1)from the panel as I have placed the feed from the generator ABOVE that switch and would connect to the line continuing to the furnace by plugging the generator into the new receptacle I place AFTER the switch  already in the line is closed, thereby preventing back-feed to the panel The neutral and ground  remain connected to the panel.Looking for simplicity as need is VERY minimal

Comment: @DougC If neutral and ground are un-bonded at the generator, then the SPST switch is fine. However when using it portable you'll want to re-bond neutral and ground.  Make sure you're using a proper (male) *inlet* for the generator feed, not a (female) outlet and a male-male "suicide cord".  No cord should ever have 2 male plugs.

Comment: The receptacle is a proper covered male plug and there is a lock-off over the inline switch.I am not sure where to bond the neutral and ground on the generator output and I THINK the schematic shows it as "unbonded"?? Not sure how to send copy of schematic

Comment: Since this generator was meant to be carried in the back of the truck and the RV to be plugged into it,I'm starting to think it may actually be bonded as the RV would have been unbonded to meet code, with the bonding occurring at the "pedestal" site OR, I suspect, at the generator since there never was a transfer switch involved between the gen. and the RV load center.Does that make sense?